# Accessing assets in iOS7 with NSBundle

Tags: ios, file, assets, nsbundle

I am having problems updating an app to iOS7 SDK. Before I've used iOS 6 SDK and accessed my mp3 file using a `NSURL` for the folder like this:

```
NSURL *folderURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"" withExtension:@"" subdirectory:@"AudioGuide"];
```

Now, using the iOS 7 SDK I always get nil as the value for `folderURL` and my audio guide doesn't find the mp3's anymore.

I've already looked into the generated .app-Bundle for the simulator (in ~/Library/Application Support/...), and I can see the "AudioGuide" folder in the root. So it's definitly there.

I am not that iOS guru and didn't really follow iOS7 updates. Has there been any changes made on how to access own assets in an app? How do I access my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doc for `- (NSURL *)URLForResource:(NSString *)name withExtension:(NSString *)extension subdirectory:(NSString *)subpath`

> Returns the file URL for the resource file identified by the specified
>   name and extension and residing in a given bundle directory.

what that means is you can get the file URL with specific type in a given subdirectory, so you should use this method call with your file name and extension.

If you are trying to read the list of files under that directory, what you can do is bundle all of your audio files in a single zip or gzipped file and you extract it in your Documents or Application Support directory when it is accessed for the very first time, then you can read it using the code below.

```
NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directory = [directories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *audioDirectoryPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AudioGuide"];


NSArray *audioFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:audioDirectoryPath];
```

Hope this helps!