# Move file from App bundle to Document folder on ios

Tags: ios

I have file in my App bundle on iOS. How can I move it to be in `Document` folder?
Can this be done through some configuration or I need to make custom code for it?

By custom code I mean:

- check is this first run of app:
- if so, move files to the `Document` folder.

Comment: You have to write custom code, you can follow this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666057/accessing-assets-in-ios7-with-nsbundle/22669347#22669347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out `NSFileManager` which allows you to **copy** files within the file system as required. You should be aware that Apple **will reject your App** if the copied file is not flagged to **NOT** backup to iCloud.

I use the following methods to copy a sqlite database from the bundle to a folder; it should work for your purpose with minor modification.

```
+ (void)copyBundleFileToStoresDirectory:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:nil]];
    NSURL *pathURL = [SVOFileSystemMethods documentsSubdirectory:@"Stores" skipBackup:YES];

    if (fileURL)
    {
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:fileURL toURL:pathURL error:&error])
        {
            //           NSLog(@"File successfully copied");
        }
        else
        {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"error", nil) message: NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to copy database from bundle.", nil)
                                      delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            NSLog(@"Error description-%@ \n", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"Error reason-%@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
        }
    }
}


+ (NSURL *) documentsSubdirectory:(NSString *)subdirectoryName skipBackup:(BOOL) skipBackup
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:subdirectoryName];  //untested change here -- was literal @"/Stores"

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
        NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataPath];
        if (skipBackup)
            [SVOFileSystemMethods addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:finalURL];      // flag to exclude from backups.
        return finalURL;
    }
    else
        return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataPath]; // already existed
}


//
//  flags URL to exclude from backup
//
+ (BOOL) addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can't "move" files from the app bundle to the app directory, since that requires deleting them from the bundle. You'll get an access denied, assuming your code is set up right.

You can "copy" files however, since that it simply a read.

In my case, I had a whole bunch of files that I wanted to move to the app's Library directory but was unable. Additionally, the copy operation was far too costly because of the quantity of files.

In this case, I changed the app logic to check for "fresh" information first (that I would save to the Library folder), & if it wasn't there then fall back to the App bundle to look for an old/original copy of the file.